# Facebook GraphAPI '/me/friends?fields=id,name,email,picture&limit=500' doesn't return email

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, react-native

Facebook GraphAPI '/me/friends?fields=id,name,email,picture&limit=500' doesn't return email, only returns id, name, picture. Getting only friends who use the app, that's okay, but why email is not returned?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either for privacy reasons or because the friends did not authorized the email permission. Also, not everyone uses Facebook with an email. I just tested it, and it seems that you really cannot get emails of friends with the API call.

Either way, just store the email in your database when the user authorizes your App and you will have all emails of friends by matching their IDs.